# Add specific cells to a combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add values that are within two distinct cells to my combobox and I cant seem to get it to work! I know that I can populate a range of cells into my combo box:

```
Me.ComboBox3.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C917:C927").Value
```

But how would I add `c2, c4, c6` to a combobox?

Comment: The cell is also within a specific sheet, so I need to define the sheet and then add the two cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to use for each to loop trough the data and add items to the combo box

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2,C4,C6")
    Me.ComboBox3.AddItem c.Value
Next
```

To remove values use

```
For n = Me.ComboBox3.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Me.ComboBox3.RemoveItem n
Next n
```

Comment: That is perfect, I also realised that it is possible to add an item like this `Me.ListBox1.AddItem Range("B14").Value` but that didnt reference the sheet so thank you

Comment: Yup, that's equalent, you can do it refering to a sheet by just doing `me.listbox1.additem sheets("mysheet").range("mycell").value` but when needed to add from multiple cells it's more efficient to use a loop than write each addition in it's own line..